# Try to internationalize flutter application with BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, bloc

I tried to integrate all my logic related to the change of language in a block. I am using the flutter_bloc package which gives me access to the "BlocProvider" method. However, I get an error when I try to expand my block.

Here is the error:

```
Error: Type argument 'TranslationsBloc' doesn't conform to
the bound 'Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>' of the type variable 'T' on 'BlocProvider'.
```

Here is the code:

#### main.dart

```
return BlocProvider<TranslationsBloc>(
      bloc: translationsBloc,
      child: StreamBuilder<String>(
        ...
```

#### MainBloc.dart

```
abstract class BlocBase {
  void dispose();
}

class TranslationsBloc implements BlocBase {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`BlocProvider` will recognize the type of the child `bloc` automatically without needing to explicitly mentioning it, so removing the type provided to it will fix your issue:

```
  return BlocProvider(
    bloc: translationsBloc,
    child: StreamBuilder<String>(
    ...
```

Comment: yes I tried, but I got this message: `'TranslationsBloc' doesn't extend 'Bloc'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Bloc'.dart(type_argument_not_matching_bounds)
Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Tried to infer 'TranslationsBloc' for 'T' which doesn't work:
  Type parameter 'T' declared to extend 'Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>'.
The type 'TranslationsBloc' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'bloc' declared as     'T'`

Comment: You also need to extend `BlocBase` rather than implementing it, I use this approach in my personal projects and it works smoothly.

Comment: Can you try this ```class LanguageBloc extends Bloc<LanguageEvent, LanguageState>``` and add language event with language state to maintain the state